# How to save class name in cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I designed 2 themes for my website (daymode and nightmode) but when i refresh the page, it doesn't remember the last mode. How can i set a cookie to remember the last selected theme ? Here's the code :

**HTML**

```
<body class="daymode">
<button data-switch-contrast aria-hidden>Switch Colors</button>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.daymode {
//daymode content
}

.nightmode {
//nightmode content
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('[data-switch-contrast]').addEventListener('click', function() {
document.body.classList.toggle('nightmode');
});
```

Comment: Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie